# Emulator qemu: could not load initrd ' ' while trying to run android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I get this error each time while trying to run Android Emulator :

```
[2014-08-13 16:21:37 - GPSSerialFix] Android Launch!
[2014-08-13 16:21:37 - GPSSerialFix] adb is running normally.
[2014-08-13 16:21:37 - GPSSerialFix] Performing com.keyproj.project.projectname.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-08-13 16:21:37 - GPSSerialFix] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'Motorolla' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2014-08-13 16:21:37 - GPSSerialFix] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Motorolla'
[2014-08-13 16:21:38 - Emulator] qemu: could not load initrd ''
```

I tried Restarting but didn't help. Is there anyway I can fix this issue?

Comment: Its not with the code...Any project that I try to compile...Even trying to Launch the emulator for hello world app I get this error.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I will solve my own issue. So I realized that this issue is because it is trying to emulate ARM processor and no kernel image for that or something like that, so I started to wonder why ARM processor.

Long story short, I had to go back to the Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager and edit the Android Virtual Device and change CPU/ABI from ARM to Intel Atom (x86) and now the error message is gone and the Android emulation loads.

Comment: That is true, but I want an emulator with a ARM Processor only and not an Intel Atom x86 Processor